# Proper usage of a center-tap transformer

Tags: transformer, analog, dc-dc-converter

I'm attempting to design a high-precision voltage source for use in an optics lab. My starting point has been [the application notes provided by Analog Devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN118fb.pdf); specifically, Fig 16:

[image]

The transformer recommended by the author is over $80 and has a very sparse datasheet. Moreover, for my application, I do not need 300V output. I have been looking around for suitable replacement parts and came across [the Power Integrations SIT1253I converter](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product_document/data_sheet/sit12xxi_family_datasheet.pdf), which seems to have a 1:10.66 turns ratio from the primary to secondary side. I am planning on providing 12V input to the start of the primary-side winding, so that the nominal maximum output of the secondary-side winding is ~128V. Moreover, I am planning on tying pins 3 and 2 together and wiring them to the control circuit depicted in the above schematic so that the voltage can be tuned from 0-128V.

Am I correctly understanding how to use this device? Is this a suitable replacement for the Pico 32195 transformer recommended in the Analog Devices application notes? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just checking applicability - this transformer can handle 2.6W max.  2.6W/128V = 20mA.  Is this an acceptable load limit?

Comment: Your “precision” design has no specs. Why is that? Please add details on rise time, step load regulation error, ripple , power , voltage, ambient T , budget, time etc. Make/buy?

Comment: Hi rdtsc, yes, I believe so. I am just trying to drive a piezo.

Comment: Hi Tony, sorry, I am a novice in EE. I am trying to drive: https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PK4FA2P1. The spec sheet does not tell me what the current / power draw of the piezo is. I'm trying to keep the voltage ripple down to 100uV maximum, and I need to be able to provide voltage within the range of 0-150V (some sub-interval of this range is ok). The ambient temperature will be stabilized with a thermoelectric cooler separately.

Comment: In any case you need a center tap primary transformer, shorting pin 2 to 3 won't work.

Comment: I Expect you to link the datasheet and compute power from all the parameters. ESR + C @ f and Vac   https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/f8c537c2794cad1c-6E38115E-02BF-31C6-8D84A893D9035327/PK4FA2P1-SpecSheet.pdf  Without that, you are wasting your time.

Comment: Learn to create a design spec for the system , just like the components, before you choose anything . Learn from existing designs by testing critical nodes for step response. Unless you prefer trial and error

Comment: Thanks carloc, that's good to know. I apologize Tony but I am a novice at this with no formal training and I don't really know what you are looking for from me.